# Анимация hover - js

Tags: javascript, анимация, hover

Есть следующий код:

```
$('.news-block_main').hover(
function(){
    $('.news-block-hover_main').css('display','block');
},
function(){
    $('.news-block-hover_main').css('display','none');
}
);
```

собственно как сделать так чтобы все это действие выполнялось плавно (аналог в css: transition)

Comment: А что если и правда сделать на `CSS`? Быстрее и плавнее в любом случае будет.

Comment: в данном случае через css не получится

Comment: Это легко делается, что Вы! Или доступа к стилям нет о_О?

Comment: Я же говорю в данном случае это не получится. Как бы я не ковырял css - ничего не меняется

Comment: Вот: https://jsfiddle.net/t6kmbp4w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:block` в CSS нельзя сделать плавным при проявлении, так как это не предусмотрено.
Тут нужно использовать `opacity` или `visibility`.

Ну а правильным вариантом будут не прямая смена стилей, а замена `class`.

css

```
div{
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out 0.5s;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out 0.5s;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-out 0.5s;
     transition: all 1s ease-out 0.5s;
}
.show{
     opacity: 1;
}
.hide{
     opacity: 0;
}
```

js

```
$('div').hover(
function(){
    $('div').attr('class', 'show');
},
function(){
    $('div').attr('class', 'hide');
}
);
```

Как-то так, хотя jQuery уже есть предусмотренные методы на такой случай.

Comment: скорее даже addClass()/removeClass()

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал так:

```
$('.news-block_main').hover(
function(){$('.news-block-hover_main').animate({height: "toggle"}, 200)('display','block');},
function(){$('.news-block-hover_main').animate({height: "toggle"}, 200)('display','none');}
);
```

но как сделать появление анимации снизу вверх? В данный момент она появляется (сверху-вниз)

Comment: Добавьте еще и стили позиционирования для активного и пасивного вида.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").hover(function () {
  $(this).stop(true).slideToggle();
});

$("div").hover(function () {
   $(this).find('вложенный див').stop(true).slideToggle();
});
```